# PWA workbox-4.0.0 maxEntries limit is currently 50 in NetworkFirst strategies

Tags: caching, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb, workbox

Problem:- Using below code snippet we have increased maxEntries to 100, Only 50 entries are getting cached.Is there any other workbox strategies which will help us to store/cache more than 50 entries of API (Currently we have requirement to store approx 450-500 entries)

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('.+\/api\/'),
      workbox.strategies.networkFirst({
      cacheName: 'myapp-apiCache',
          plugins : [
             new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
                 maxEntries: 100,
                 maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 // 30 days
              })
         ]
 })
);
```